# Xpath выборка последовательных элементов, следующих друг за другом без пропусков

Tags: xpath

Допустим у нас такой HTML

```
<div>
   Текст1 тест2 <b>текст3</b> текст4 текст5

   текст6 <b>текст7</b><b>текст8</b> текст9

   <b>текст 10</b> текст 11
</div>
```

Необходимо выбрать повторяющиеся друг за другом теги  в количестве равном 2. Другими словам тег  должен повторяться например 2 раза. Между тегами не должно быть текста или других тегов.

Выборка должна дать теги с текстом "текст7" и "текст8".

Буду благодарен за совет и любую информацию в поиске решения.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос утратил актуальность. Решил задачу альтернативным путем. 
Использую регулярное выражение.

```
$re = '/(<b>(.+?)<\/b> <b>(.+?)<\/b>)/mi';
$str = 'Барбарис оттавский <b>Суперба</b> <b>Superba</b>): описание и уход. Для создания <b> asdf </b> <b>aaa </b> неповторимого вида участка используется много <b>aaa </b> сложных и не совсем... ';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

// Print the entire match result
var_dump($matches);
```